# Images in CollectionView disappear on scrolling

Tags: image, scroll, maui, collectionview, memorystream

I am currently working on a `CollectionView` to display a number of images on .NET MAUI. I am not using any third party library to manage image caching. I am able to start a task that eventually takes advantage of `INotifyPropertyChanged` in the inner model of `DataTemplate` to update the `ImageSource` property of my image and it works pretty well. Unfortunately, though, when I scroll the `CollectionView` I lose the image from within the `Grid` cell, despite examining the `ObservableCollection<T>` which contains the `ImageSource` property I can find the `MemoryStream`, and **it has not been disposed** elsewhere.

I attach the methods I use to retrieve the images and to create the streams below:

```
// Here's a portion of my ViewModel...

private async Task CaricaDati()
{
    try
    {
        InFetching = true;
        AllFetched = false;

        files = await storageService.GetAllBlobsAsync(idCantiere, "Rapporti");
        
        IEnumerable<AllegatoModel> pageAllegati = (await CaricaDatiSub(0, paginaAllegati)).Select(f => new AllegatoModel
        {
            Nome = f.Name,
            ImageAspect = Utility.GetTipoFile(Path.GetExtension(f.Name)) == Enumerazioni.TipoFile.Immagine ||
                Utility.GetTipoFile(Path.GetExtension(f.Name)) == Enumerazioni.TipoFile.PDF ? Aspect.Fill : Aspect.Center
        });

        if (pageAllegati is not null && pageAllegati.Any())
        {
            Allegati = new ObservableRangeCollection<AllegatoModel>(pageAllegati);
            _ = Task.Run(() => DownloadImagesAsync(pageAllegati));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        AppCenterEventManager.TrackError(ex, string.Empty);
        UIMessagesManager.ShowMessage(Stringhe.ATTENZIONE, Stringhe.ERR_IMPREVISTO);
    }
    finally { InFetching = false; }
}

private async Task DownloadImagesAsync(IEnumerable<AllegatoModel> pageAllegati)
{            
    if (pageAllegati is not null)
    {
        foreach (var item in pageAllegati)
        {
            var memStream = await storageService.DownloadStreamAsync(idCantiere, item.Nome);
            Allegati.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Nome == item.Nome).Anteprima = ImageSource.FromStream(() => memStream);
        }
    }
}

// This is my StorageService.cs class...

public async Task<MemoryStream> DownloadStreamAsync(string cName, string bName)
{
    BlobContainerClient container = blobService.GetBlobContainerClient(cName);
    BlobClient file = container.GetBlobClient(bName);

    if (file.Exists())
    {
        MemoryStream str = new();
        await file.DownloadToAsync(str);
        str.Position = 0;
        return str;
    }
    else
        return null;
}
```

Is there any strategy I am missing? How is it that the `Grid` cell becomes empty if the `StreamImageSource` is still there?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the lifetime of the `MemoryStream`, since it needs to be created in the same context of the `CollectionView` for it to be kept alive.

Here's the correct way to use it:

```
private async Task DownloadImagesAsync(IEnumerable<AllegatoModel> pageAllegati)
{            
    if (pageAllegati is not null)
    {
        foreach (var item in pageAllegati)
        {
            MemoryStream memStream = await storageService.DownloadStreamAsync(idCantiere, item.Nome);
            byte[] strArray = Utility.StreamToByteArray(memStream);
            Allegati.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Nome == item.Nome).Anteprima = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(strArray));
        }
    }
}
```

You need to pass through a byte array transformation and then go back to Stream.